# How to change the language for specific view elements?

Tags: cakephp

I am using the translation behaviour function: __() to translate things. It works great. Unformtunately when I change the language in the controller like this:

```
Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');
```

it changes the language for the whole site :(

Is there a way to translate let say only specific parts? (in view)
For example, the language of the whole app is in english. But for some $this->element I want it in german.

My attempt:  in the view I change the language like this:

```
<?php
    Configure::write('Config.language', 'deu');
    echo __("Hello World");
?>
```

It works only when the CakeSession::read part in l18n.php is removed:

```
    if (empty($language)) {
        // if (CakeSession::started()) {
        //  $language = CakeSession::read('Config.language');
        // }
        if (empty($language)) {
            $language = Configure::read('Config.language');
        }
    }
```

I could rewrite the l18n.php so it works for me but it is core and I don't want to touch it. Is there a way to CakeSession::write in view? cakephp doc says [it is not possible](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/session.html).

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate - but what's to stop you Configure::write'ing the language to deu and then back when you've finished?

Comment: but when I Configure::write in the controller it will translate everything, the whole app. I want to translate specific elements in the view (which are included by $this->element() )

Comment: I tried it also in the view but the language won't change. :(

Comment: Your attempt isn't in the question - unless the language is defined in the session [that just works](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/I18n/I18n.php#L208-L215).

Comment: yes it should work but it isn't, if I set the language in the view and print the $language in l18n.php is not changed. It will only change when I change the language in the controller, not the view.

Comment: I am sorry, it works!  I mean it works when the CakeSession part is removed from the l18n.php just like in my post. How can I change the CakeSession in view?

Comment: with CakeSession::write =)? I'll let you answer your own question.

Comment: thanks @AD7six! it works with CakeSession::write :)

Answer (score 0):

You may create a folder named as your desired language inside your elements folder then call it.

Taking brazilian portuguese as an example: `<?php echo $this->element('pt_BR/your_element'); ?>`

Comment: yeah good idea. But what I did was I have overriden the translate function (underscore) by using my own php in vendor directory and using namespaces. Works good.